# ng repeat on a array to filter a key on another object to get the associated value and use watch on that value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let say i have a object called,

`scope.rec = {a: 2, b: 3, name: a,b};`

And i split the "name" key like `scope.x = scope.rec.name.split(",");` then scope.x will become an array.

Now i need to iterate over "scope.x" in the view and get the value associated with the matching property name on `scope.rec`. I only want to iterate over the valid property names, so I will need to use a filter on `scope.x`, but it is not working as I would expect.

Once I get the first part working, I will also need to add functionality to multiply the values of the `scope.rec` properties together - in the example above, it is only 2 numbers (a,b), but it could be more than 2.

Below is the code that I tried.

```
 scope.x  =
 scope.rec.name.split(",");
scope.myFilter = function(y) {
   if(!scope.rec.hasOwnProperty(y)) return false;
   scope.ys = Number(scope.rec[y]);
    return scope.ys;
        };
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="y in x | filter:myFilter">
            <label for="{{y}}">{{y}}</label>
            <input type="number" id="{{y}}" value={{ys}}>
    </div>
<div><input id="calc" type="number" ng-model="calc()" disabled></div>
```

Now the `ys` in the input is same for both inputs, and the `calc()` function does not calculate the values correctly.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: what does calc() do ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.-  basically calc() multiply's the array's values and is returned to the "calc" id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your filter (at least how you use it in your view) will receive an array with all elements, not just one. So you need to return a complete array

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(arrayOfYs, recFromScope) {
      var filtered = [];
      arrayOfYs.forEach(function(y){
        if(!recFromScope.hasOwnProperty(y)) return;
        // if the value in the object is already a number, it is not necessary to use Number. If it is not the case, add it
        filtered.push(scope.rec[y]);
      });
      return filtered;
    }
});
```

and return the filtered data.

According to your view, you need to use angular filters.

for you input you should use this

```
<input type="number" id="{{y}}" value={{y}}>
```

although I would remove that id - ids needs to be unique and probably there are values repeated.

for your `calc()` function you can use reduce to multiply them

```
$scope.calc = function(){
    return $scope.filteredItems.reduce(function(prev, current) {
         return prev * current;
    }, 1);
};
```

and to get a reference to `$scope.filteredItems` use this in your view

```
<div ng-repeat="y in (filteredItems = (x | filter:myFilter:rec))">
```

Comment: I thought the same thing about the filter receiving an array, but the way the OP is using it, it actually only gives single values. You would have to do `module.filter("myFilter", function () { ... })` to get the array of values.

Comment: you're right. let me edit it. I totally forgot aobut it

Comment: Filter syntax in view will need to change: `x | myFilter`. You will also have to pass in `scope.rec`, as scope is undefined in your updated filter function. Also, `module.filter()` returns a function, which does the actual filtering. Should look like so: `module.filter("myFilter", function () { return function (items) { /* do filtering here */ return filteredItems; });`

Comment: Which is as far as I got, but kept getting infinite digest loop, and had other things I needed to get to, so I scrapped it.

Comment: updated filter definition. and View. Let me add scope.rec

Comment: done. I believe now is a correct response. I got confused with his code and mine and I am also at work, so I mixed everything. Thanks for pointing out the problems with my answer !

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.result = 1;
  $scope.recObj = {};
  $scope.rec = {
    a: 2,
    b: 3,
    c: 5,
    name: 'a,b,c,d'
  };

  function initData() {
    var dataKeysArr = $scope.rec.name.split(",");

    for (var dataKey of dataKeysArr) {
      if ($scope.rec.hasOwnProperty(dataKey)) {
        $scope.recObj[dataKey] = $scope.rec[dataKey];
      }
    }
  };

  initData();

  // Watch
  $scope.$watchCollection(
    "recObj",
    function() {

      $scope.result = 1;
      for (var dataKey in $scope.recObj) {
        $scope.result *= $scope.recObj[dataKey];
      };
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController">

    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in recObj">
      <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
      <input type="number" id="{{key}}" ng-model="recObj[key]">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="calc" type="number" ng-model="result" disabled>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```